# How can I write a matcher that is generic to different object types and can infer what to inspect based on annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

Please can you advise how I can use annotations to achieve the below.

I have different objects with attributes for example

Address has 
 addresscode, addressid, address line 1, address line 2, postcode

BankDetails has
bankid, bank name, bank address, account no, sort code

The primary key fields in my above objects can change depending upon the object type. For example Address has primary key as addresscode and addressid while BankDetails has primary key as bankid. The primary key can be a composite key in some scenarios.

I would like to annotate the variables that are primary key with @primary and then have a class called 'Matcher' that takes in two object of a certain type and compares for the primary key and returns true if they match. I am hoping this way I can keep the matcher generic and pass in any object type.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you already have an annotation @Primary. You can create a method that, given an object, scans its fields and build an array of keys considering the values of the fields annotated with @Primary:

```
private static Object[] getCompositeKey(
    final Object object )
{
    final List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    for( final Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields() ) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible( true );
            if( field.getAnnotation( Primary.class ) != null ) {
                keys.add( field.get( object ) );
            }
        } catch( final Exception e ) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }

    if( keys.isEmpty() ) {
        //no keys
        return new Object[]{};
    }
    return keys.toArray();
}
```

Then, if you want to check if two objects has the exact same keys, just create the array of keys for both and then compare the arrays.